# How to access key in a nested object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

```js
{
  "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": {
    "_id": "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a",
    "username": "dhruv1999",
    "fullname": "dhruv parmar",
    "email": "dhruv@gmail.com",
    "phone": "7045691556",
    "password": "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "5def2747d135311a747a9660": {
    "_id": "5def2747d135311a747a9660",
    "username": "dhruv1998",
    "fullname": "parmar",
    "email": "dhruvkp@gmail.com",
    "phone": "704591556",
    "password": "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

How can i get all the email such as dhruv@gmail.com, dhruvkp@gmail.com

I tried doing but not getting the email.

```js
const userMap = {};
users.forEach(user => {
  userMap[user._id] = user;
});

userMap.forEach((obj) => {
      keys = Object.keys(obj);
      keys.forEach((key) => {
        console.log(obj[key].email);

      });
```

Comment: is `userMap` the object itself?

Comment: Can you explain more about your object?

Comment: Is this a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the following doesn't work is because `userMap` is an object (you're also not closing your outer `.forEach` loop, which will be a syntax error) :

```
userMap.forEach((obj) => {
  keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach((key)=>{
    console.log(obj[key].email);
  });
```

In order to use `.forEach()`, you need to use it on an array (or an array-like collection). Instead, you can get the `Object.values()` of your object. `Object.values()` gives back an array, so you can then use `.map()` on it to get the email properties:

```js
const obj = {"5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": { "_id": "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a", "username": "dhruv1999", "fullname": "dhruv parmar", "email": "dhruv@gmail.com", "phone": "7045691556", "password": "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna", "__v": 0 }, "5def2747d135311a747a9660": { "_id": "5def2747d135311a747a9660", "username": "dhruv1998", "fullname": "parmar", "email": "dhruvkp@gmail.com", "phone": "704591556", "password": "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm", "__v": 0 } }

const res = Object.values(obj).map(({email}) => email);
console.log(res);
console.log(res.join(', ')); // use `.join()` for string output
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for...in` to iterate all keys of the object. Because `forEach` is an array method and `userMap` is an object so it can't use the method.

```
for (const id in userMap) {
  console.log(userMap[id].email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of our object is `object`.

```
let object={
  "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": {
    "_id": "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a",
    "username": "dhruv1999",
    "fullname": "dhruv parmar",
    "email": "dhruv@gmail.com",
    "phone": "7045691556",
    "password": "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "5def2747d135311a747a9660": {
    "_id": "5def2747d135311a747a9660",
    "username": "dhruv1998",
    "fullname": "parmar",
    "email": "dhruvkp@gmail.com",
    "phone": "704591556",
    "password": "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm",
    "__v": 0
  }
}

for(let obj in object){
  console.log(object[obj].email)
}
```

For in loop gives all keys present in your `object` i.e `5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a` and `5def2747d135311a747a9660` and from there you can access email property.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should do the trick
`Object.entries(users).map(([key,value]) => value.email)`

- `Object.entries(users)` returns an array of key and value array
- `.map(([key,value]) => value.email)` will extract email field from all users

  - `[key,value]` is a [destructuring assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) an easy way to assign the array values to variables

Answer (score 0):

using `for...in loop`

```
for (const key in array) {
    let obj = array[key];
    console.log(obj.email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method is available for Arrays only. Hence you may want to use `for...in` here to iterate all the keys in the `userMap` object and then access the `email` key.

A working example:

```js
const userMap = {
  "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": {
    "_id": "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a",
    "username": "dhruv1999",
    "fullname": "dhruv parmar",
    "email": "dhruv@gmail.com",
    "phone": "7045691556",
    "password": "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "5def2747d135311a747a9660": {
    "_id": "5def2747d135311a747a9660",
    "username": "dhruv1998",
    "fullname": "parmar",
    "email": "dhruvkp@gmail.com",
    "phone": "704591556",
    "password": "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm",
    "__v": 0
  }
};

for (const id in userMap) {
  console.log(userMap[id].email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

```js
let data = {
  "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": {
    _id: "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a",
    username: "dhruv1999",
    fullname: "dhruv parmar",
    email: "dhruv@gmail.com",
    phone: "7045691556",
    password: "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna",
    __v: 0
  },
  "5def2747d135311a747a9660": {
    _id: "5def2747d135311a747a9660",
    username: "dhruv1998",
    fullname: "parmar",
    email: "dhruvkp@gmail.com",
    phone: "704591556",
    password: "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm",
    __v: 0
  }
};

   

Object.keys(data).forEach(item => {
  console.log(data[item].email);  //you can access email here.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code =>

```
  var data = {
    "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a": {
        "_id": "5def224170a3ec0d90dbb89a",
        "username": "dhruv1999",
        "fullname": "dhruv parmar",
        "email": "dhruv@gmail.com",
        "phone": "7045691556",
        "password": "$2a$10$UOk8E4fbkkZvSRSzQqWK4eyJ2Z.qtL4D38thfhzkxJ1pSxSFn5fna",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "5def2747d135311a747a9660": {
        "_id": "5def2747d135311a747a9660",
        "username": "dhruv1998",
        "fullname": "parmar",
        "email": "dhruvkp@gmail.com",
        "phone": "704591556",
        "password": "$2a$10$px5SK.OpP7i2Ryvg.ko/OeIbuq9XDT3luTrIBloNFCTiImUJC1BIm",
        "__v": 0
    }
}


let allEmails = '';

Object.keys(data).map((item) => {

    allEmails = allEmails + data.item.email + ','

})
console.log(allEmails) // here you will get all emails
```

Try this it will work definitely.

Comment: I think you want to use `Object.values(data)` instead of `Object.keys(data)`

Comment: It should look like this `let allEmails = Object.values(data).map(item => item.email).join(','); console.log(allEmails);`

Comment: You were wrong because Object.values(data) returns array of keys and i want that for looping Object.values(data) returns values but i dont need it.

Comment: @RahulGupta no, qoomon is correct, `item.email` doesn't make any sense if `item` is the _key_ because then it will just be a string, and no property `.email` exists on a string. It makes sense if it is the `value` as that would be the object, where `.email` access the email property. Also currently, you're using `.map()` without using its return value. `.map()` isn't intended to be used this way. Instead, you can use `.forEach()` if all you intend on doing is iterating and causing side-effects.